# How can i stop Call Broadcast massages in micromax yu yunique

Tags: instant-messaging

getting lots of msg from CB channel in my micromax yu yunique cell. Please let me how can i stop. I have checked many time in my massage setting but i didn't get hug results. can help me, So let me know

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > More (In Android 5.1.1) > Emergency Broadcasts
There some options inside the above settings location.

Read the options carefully and set or unset whichever you want. I hope this will help you.